# integral of unit step function or delta function in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I want to use `int` or `integral` function of matlab to calculate the integral of the delta function, I can't use `int` function because of the input, I give it is not expression. also, `integral` function returns a value which it isn't something below picture is the function which I want to produce it must be with delta function
[image]

this is my code that return ma an error:

```
t=-5:0.01:5;
ydelta=u(t+1)-u(t);
h=int(u(t+1)-u(t));
plot(t,h)
```

this is `u` function:

```
function y=u(t)
y=(t>=0);
end
```

and this is an error :
Undefined function 'int' for input arguments of type 'double'.
but this does not matter because the problem is the input of `int` function which must be expression.

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Question is a bit confusing: unit step function is not the same as "delta function", and neither is the square pulse u(t+1)-u(t). (Delta function is not really a function that you can evaluate numerically, except in discrete time). Is there a reason you are not just integrating it "by hand" using a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

For integration, you have to use the `integral` function.
For more info: https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html

Comment: `integral` function returns a value but I have to plot the outcome so I can't use `integral` function.

Comment: and also the input must be a function but my input is a vector.

Comment: If you want to plot the outcome (I suppose you mean the integral area) you can use the 'area' graphical function. For the second problem, all you have to do is to transform your curve code into a function and pass the handle to the 'integral' function.